# Why iterating is more preferable than random access

Tags: java, list

[The following page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator(int)) states

> The List interface provides four methods for positional (indexed)
>   access to list elements. Lists (like Java arrays) are zero based. Note
>   that these operations may execute in time proportional to the index
>   value for some implementations (the LinkedList class, for example).
>   **Thus, iterating over the elements in a list is typically preferable to
>   indexing through it if the caller does not know the implementation.**

What does this mean? Does it mean I should prefer

```
ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list.listIterator(0);
iterator.next()
iterator.next()
```

over

```
list.get(1)
```

If so, why? If the underlying list implementation is plain Array, `get` will be executed in constant time. But using iterator it's `O(n)`. What am I missing here?

Do they mean I should use `list.listIterator(1);` instead of `list.get(1)`?

Comment: I think, documentation says iterating is better then random access in case when you need to go through all or almost all elements of the List. If you just need to take nth element - it would be better to call get().

Comment: What happens if the `List` is a '`LinkedList`? `list.get(n)` requires traversing the elements before it. The loop becomes `O(n^2)`

Comment: @greg is exactly correct.  The key phrase here is "indexing through it;" in other words accessing all members of the List by index.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. But you should prefer

```
for (Integer value : list) {
    // do something with value
}
```

(or a loop using the list's iterator explicitly)

over

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Integer value = list.get(i);
    // do something with value
}
```

If the list is a linked list, the first one is O(N), whereas the second one is O(N^2). Indeed, at each iteration, it needs to traverse the list (from the start or the end, depending on the value of `i`) until it gets to the `i`th position. That doesn't happen when you use an Iterator or a foreach loop.

Another good reason is that, in the case of concurrent lists, the Iterator can be consistent (i.e. iterate on a consistent snapshot of the list made when the iterator is created). That can't be the case with an iteration using the indices of the list.

Comment: This explanation is perfect but I have a doubt here. If the List is an ArrayList, Then both work in `O(n)` or not? I think they should work in `O(n)` since `ArrayList` provides access in `O(1)` time.

Comment: Yes, in case of an ArrayList, both are O(N).

Comment: No. The loop has N iterations. For each iteration, on average, it must traverse N/4 nodes (best case: i == 0 or i == size -1; worst case: i == size / 2). N * N / 4 is O(N^2).

Comment: Hi @JBNizet , I know this is not right place , but could you please take a look to this question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909146/jpa-hibernate-query-return-wrong-result-when-before-it-executed-other-query

Answer (score 3):

I'm almost certain it's implying that **to loop through all elements in a list** it is preferable to iterate rather than, for example:

```
// possibly slow depending on List implementation used
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
{
    Foo bar = list.get(i);
}
```

In the case of a `LinkedList` where random access is not O(1), every single time you call `list.get(i)` you are having to iterate from the start all the way to `i` which is unnecessary.

---

Your example of pure *random access* (rather than looping through everything) is:

1. In the case of a `LinkedList`, more verbose (but basically what
   `get(i)` does under the hood)
2. In the case of an `ArrayList`, actually slower than `get(i)`

Answer (score 2):

What the Javadoc is talking about is this situation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Object o = list.get(i);
}
```

If the implementation of `list` is an `ArrayList` then you are right, access to the underlying array will be constant time for each particular element (`O(n)` for the whole list). However, what if it is a `LinkedList`? To get to element `n` in a linked list, you have to iterate through `[0, 1, ... n - 2, n - 1]` before you get to element `n`. This is now very inefficient if you do this for every element in the array.

Therefore, a better approach is to write the for loop using an iterator:

```
// uses the iterator under the hood.
for (Object o : list) {

}
```

In this case, the `ArrayList` iterator will just walk along the array, so just as fast as the first for loop, and for the `LinkedList` it keeps track of the position in the list so you do not have to walk the whole list to get to the next element.

Comment: Correct, except since a LinkedList is actually a doubly-linked list, it will start from the end when i is closer to the end than the beginning. That doesn't change the runtime complexity, though.

Comment: @JBNizet, good point, thanks for bringing it up, I had forgotten about that.