# Jpa/Hibernate query return wrong result when before it executed other query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I have very strange case with jpa/hibernate.

I have 4 entities , something like this

```
entity County  has Set<City>
City has Set<CityRegion>
CityRegion has Set<House>
```

I have 2 queries in DAO(in 2 methods). I use QueryDsl for JPA, but it generates those 2 jpa queries.

```
select distinct county
from County county
  inner join fetch county.cities as city
  inner join fetch city.cityRegions as cityRegion
  inner join fetch cityRegion.houses as house
where city.id = ?1


    select distinct county
from County county
  inner join fetch county.cities as city
  inner join fetch city.cityRegions as cityRegion
  inner join fetch cityRegion.houses as house
where house.id = ?1
```

When I call only second query from service class it works fine. But when I call first query and then call second (in same service method), second query returns same( in this case wrong) result as first one. And I cann't find house which is queried by id. Also that house does not belong to that city.

In log generated native sql looks fine and correct.

I don't have second level cache. maybe there is some problem with transactions and first level cache ?

**UPDATE** Actually it always return result from first query, I change the order of queries and now it second query again returns same as first query call. It seems there is like some cache. Like you run query first time and second time hibernate returns same result, is this possible ? But I can see both sql queries in log.

**UPDATE 2**
Code looks something like this

```
  @Service
    public class CountryService {

    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository  countryRepo;
     public CountryService(CountryRepository countryRepo){
       this.countryRepo = countryRepo
     } 

     public List<Country> getByFilter(int cityId, int houseId){
       List<Country> a = this.countryRepo.getByCity(cityId);
       List<Country> b this.countyRepo.getByHouseId(houseId);
       return merge(a, b);
     }
    }


    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class CountryRepository {

     @PersistenceContext
      private EntityManager entityManager;

        public List<Country> getByCity(int id){}

        public List<Country> getByHouse(int id){}
    }
```

**UPDATE 3**
If I do `entityManager.clear();` it works fine,
I investigated and find out that both dao methods use same hibernate session. I think this leads to this problem. Myabe I need to somehow force spring and hibernate to create new Session for each method call ?

Project use Spring boot , jpa/hibernate. Thanks.

Comment: share your service class please along with ur DAO's

Comment: why you are not returning anything in your methond in the service?

Comment: Can you correct your code, so it can compile ? There are many errors that make your post hard to understand : No return, getByHouse / getByHouseId

Comment: Sorry this is not a real code. I cannot post real  code :(  
I think here the main question is how can one method call change return result of other method, Since both of them works fine if they called separately.

Comment: Even though it is not a real code, you should provide a code that can compile. It's the main rule if you want to get an helpful answer : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why are you even executing 2 queries? You can do one, the amount of queries shouldn't matter, as long as you haven't executed it you should get a correct result. If you don't get that there is something wrong in your setup. However as you posted too little information you wouldn't get a solution to your problem. Show some implementation, configuration etc. etc.

Comment: Well you are right. I change it to one query. I didn't realize that i can do it with 1 query. But i will try find problem with this approach. And put answer here

Comment: Too sad that I realized this after spending 5 hours on this issue. But I thin if you put your comment before it will defenetly help me :) so thank you. There are like 50 views to this question and no one suggested to have 1 query instead of 2. Actually original queries are not so simple but i managed to replace them by 1 query.

Comment: Thank you @user1321466, your update 3 helped me. I'm using query dsl to fetch an entity after its updated and always getting `LazyInitializationException` until I added `entityManager.clear()` before my fetch. I don't know if this is good solution but at least I know where to look now.